# Tkinter: writing if statement based on user selections in drop down menu (Python)

Tags: python, forms, if-statement, input, tkinter

I have the following code which creates a pop-up box using TKinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_button():
#     for i, var in enumerate(o_vars):
#         print('OptionMenu {}: {}'.format(i, var.get()))
#     print()

    print('ListBox:', l.curselection())
    for i in l.curselection():
        print('option:', OPTIONS[i])
    print()


# --- main ---

OPTIONS = ["Script 1","Script 2","Script 3","Script 4","Script 5"]

root = tk.Tk()

# --- Listbox ---

tk.Label(root, text='Listbox', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

l = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='multiple')
l.pack()
l.insert('end', *OPTIONS)

# --- others ---

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

I select Script 2 and Script 5 in the ListBox.

[image]

I am struggling to write code that does the following:

a) if I selected Script 2 in Listbox, I want to print "running Script2"
b) if I selected Script 5 in Listbox, I want to print "running Script5"

Below is the code I have tried by it errors out:

```
if l.curselection() == OPTIONS[1]:
    print ('running script 2')
if l.curselection() == OPTIONS[4]:
    print ('running script 5')
```

The error is attached below:

[image]

When I try to trouble shoot using the following print statement I get the following error:

```
print(l.curselection())
```

[image]

*Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: When do you run this code: `if l.curselection() == OPTIONS[1]:`? The error message implies you are doing that after the root window has been destroyed. "invalid command name .87326560" implies the widget has been destroyed.

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback.  you are right...I did destroy the widget after running the if l.curselection() == OPTIONS[1]: code.  This time around, I did not destroy the widget... but it just keeps running without printing anything at all.  Thoughts?

Comment: the l.curselection() is not outputting what you think. Adding an else statement would show you that the if statement is false.

Comment: As a suggestion, why dont you add those print statements to your on_button(). Maybe something like print("running %s" % OPTIONS[i])

Comment: Your code works for me as expected. Not sure what else you want.

Comment: @Aly: your print script does work.  ultimately, I want to say if Script1 is selected, run 'Script 1 Jupyter Notebook'.  If Script2 is selected, run 'Script 2 Jupyter Notebook'.  I have the scripts already written but I need to figure out how to write the if statement to call them.

Comment: you got explanation in previous question

Comment: @furas: when I tried the print statement you had previously recommended : "print(l.curselection())" it just keeps running and nothing gets printed out...

Comment: @PineNuts0 the `print('ListBox:', l.curselection())` in your code works for me. What is what is not working? Your question as it is written does not make sense to me.

Comment: it doesn't work because you have error `if l.curselection() == OPTIONS[1]:` - probably you put this in wrong place but you didn't show us where did you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l.curselection()` resturns tuple with indexes like `(0,2,4)`. To get strings you have to use them with `OPTIONS`

```
for idx in l.curselection():

    if OPTIONS[idx] == "Script 1":
        print('Run script number 1')
    elif OPTIONS[idx] == "Script 2":
        print('Run script number 2')
    # ...
```

Or you can use indexes directly

```
for idx in l.curselection():

    if idx == 0:
        print('Run script number 1')
    elif idx == 1:
        print('Run script number 2')
    # ...
```

You can even keep your scripts on list in the same order as text in OPTION

```
scripts = [
    'first-script.py', 'second-script.py', 'third-script.py',
]

for idx in l.curselection():
    print('Run script:', scripts[idx])
```

---

**EDIT:** Working code with different examples how to use information from `l.curselection()`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_button():

    # different examples with `curselection()`

    for idx in l.curselection():
        if OPTIONS[idx] == 'Script 1':
           print('Running first script')
        elif OPTIONS[idx] == 'Script 2':
           print('Running second script')
        elif OPTIONS[idx] == 'Script 3':
           print('Running third script')


    for idx in l.curselection():
        if idx == 0:
           print('Running first script')
        elif idx == 1:
           print('Running second script')
        elif idx == 2:
           print('Running third script')

    for idx in l.curselection():
           print('Running script:', OPTIONS[idx])

    for idx in l.curselection():
           print('Running script:', scripts[idx])

# --- main ---

scripts = ["first.py", "second.py", "third.py"]

OPTIONS = ["Script 1", "Script 2", "Script 3"]

root = tk.Tk()

# --- Listbox ---

tk.Label(root, text='Listbox', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

l = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='multiple')
l.pack()
l.insert('end', *OPTIONS)

# --- others ---

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it worked!  thank you so so so much.  I cannot express how grateful I am for helping me resolve this all the way from last night.  THANK YOU!